# How to validate the signature of an XML using signed xml and public key only (no private key/cert)

Tags: python

I am new to xml signature validation, failed to find any code for signature validation with only public key (private key not available). kindly help with the code

The content of my xml looks as below:

```
<Manifest version="21.12.2" dateTime="2021-12-02T12:04:38+05:30" baseLocation="xxx.com" baseLocationAccessProtocols="HTTPS">
    <SoftwareComponent dateTime="2021-11-30T11:27:27Z" size="128408" packageType="EFI" Version="X00" vendorVersion="1.1" releaseDate="December 01, 2021" path="xxx" releaseID="JJF" packageID="JJF" identifier="fd0a22d3" schemaVersion="3.0"/>
    <SoftwareComponent dateTime="2021-11-30T13:22:06Z" size="301976" packageType="EFI" Version="X00" vendorVersion="1.1" releaseDate="December 01, 2021" path="xxx" releaseID="YRF" packageID="YRF" identifier="36c166d1" schemaVersion="3.0"/>
    <Prerequisites/>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>kk5SAcGdiv9lavalXD2Un7EN=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>iR2gZbHx6Accev8TNsokai2WUZCQVpd9G24MUqUM==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
</Manifest>
```

I use the following code to validate the signature

```py
dom=parse(<signedXml>)
signtr_node = dom.getElementsByTagName("Signature")
if not signtr_node:
        print("Error:Signature node not available")
    for node in signtr_node:
        if not node.getElementsByTagName("SignatureValue"):
           continue
        else:
            node_val = node.getElementsByTagName("SignatureValue")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            if not node_val:
                print("SignatureValue node not available")
            else:
                print("SignatureValue : %s" % node_val)
                with open(key_file_name, 'rb') as f:
                    key = f.read()
                import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
                tree = ET.parse(file_name)
                root = tree.getroot()
                print(root)
                try:
                    verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(root,require_x509=False, x509_cert = key).signed_xml
                    print("Data is : %s" % verified_data)
                except Exception as exce:
                    print(exce)
```

#Output

```
SignatureValue : iR2gZbHx6Accev8TNsokai2WUZCQVpd9G24MUqUM==
<Element 'Manifest' at 0x4591848>
Signature verification failed: bad signature
```

Instead of the `root` in above code, tried directly with signed xml too, still hits failure
I tried with PKCS1 module too and was unsuccessful.

key_file_name is the public key used to sign the xml and file_name is the signed XML

Answer (score 0):

SignatureValue is computed on canonicalized  element within a XMLDSig signature. See [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1) for more details.

Therefore, if you want to validate SignatureValue, you firsly need to extract the < SignedInfo > element, which is actually signed, and apply canonicalization on it (see < CanonicalizationMethod > element within < SignedInfo >). The returned bytes will represent the input for SignatureValue verification.

Please also do not forget to verify ds:Reference(s) elements incorporated within the signature, as on SignatureValue the verification of a signature does not stop.